# How can i loop through multidimensional array of daily dates and group them by month

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array which contains daily dates and values,
e.g:

```
Array ( [2020-03-14] => 0 [2020-03-15] => 0 [2020-03-16] => 8 [2020-03-17] => 8 [2020-03-18] => 8 [2020-03-19] => 8 [2020-03-20] => 8 )
Array ( [2020-03-21] => 0 [2020-03-22] => 0 [2020-03-23] => 8 [2020-03-24] => 8 [2020-03-25] => 8 [2020-03-26] => 8 [2020-03-27] => 8 )
Array ( [2020-03-28] => 0 [2020-03-29] => 0 [2020-03-30] => 8 [2020-03-31] => 8 [2020-04-01] => 8 [2020-04-02] => 8 [2020-04-03] => 8 )
Array ( [2020-04-04] => 0 [2020-04-05] => 0 [2020-04-06] => 8 [2020-04-07] => 8 [2020-04-08] => 8 [2020-04-09] => 8 [2020-04-10] => 0 )
Array ( [2020-04-11] => 0 [2020-04-12] => 0 [2020-04-13] => 0 [2020-04-14] => 8 [2020-04-15] => 8 [2020-04-16] => 8 [2020-04-17] => 8 )
Array ( [2020-04-18] => 0 [2020-04-19] => 0 [2020-04-20] => 08 [2020-04-21] => 08 [2020-04-22] => 08 [2020-04-23] => 08 [2020-04-24] => 08 )
Array ( [2020-04-25] => 0 [2020-04-26] => 0 [2020-04-27] => 08 [2020-04-28] => 08 [2020-04-29] => 08 [2020-04-30] => 08 [2020-05-01] => 08 )
Array ( [2020-05-02] => 0 [2020-05-03] => 0 [2020-05-04] => 8 [2020-05-05] => 8 [2020-05-06] => 8 [2020-05-07] => 8 [2020-05-08] => 0 )
Array ( [2020-05-02] => 0 [2020-05-03] => 0 [2020-05-04] => 0 [2020-05-05] => 0 [2020-05-06] => 0 [2020-05-07] => 0 [2020-05-08] => 8 )
Array ( [2020-05-09] => 0 [2020-05-10] => 0 [2020-05-11] => 08 [2020-05-12] => 08 [2020-05-13] => 08 [2020-05-14] => 08 [2020-05-15] => 08 )
```

I would like to sum the values by month and store them in another array such as:

```
//expected out
Array ([2020-March] => 96 [2020-April] => 160 [2020-May] => 88)
```

Due to there being duplicate dates in some areas i am unsure of how to achieve this outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply iterate over the overarching array, followed by a foreach in the 2nd level array. Simply check the first 7 characters of the keys and add them to their respective bracket.

```
$aggregation = [];
for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($toAggregate); $i < $iMax; ++$i) {
    foreach ($toAggregate[$i] as $date => $value) {
        $month = substr($date, 0, 7);
        if (isset($aggregation[$month])) {
            $aggregation[$month] += $value;
        } else {
            $aggregation[$month] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

If necessary, you can reformat the keys if needed to have a textual representation.